# d3js Realtime line graph with zoom and pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pan

I use d3js and want to make a realtime line graph with zoom and pan. At the beginning the "auto-refresh mode" is enabled, but if a user clicks any mouse button then the "user mode" is activated, in which the user can zoom and pan only the X-axis. Double click turns on "auto-refresh mode".

The problem is the following: I pan graphic along the X-axis (press the LMB and move the mouse). Graphic moves right (the blue line itself, see link below), but X-axis always moves from initial state not the current state (I remind you that the graphic is a realtime), i.e. regardless of whether, when we move the all graphic, X-axis always moves from the same state (in this context the state is the interval between the minimum and maximum values).

```
backRect = svg.append('rect')
        .style('stroke', 'none')
        .style('fill', '#FFF')
        .style('fill-opacity', 0)
        .attr({
            x: margins.left,
            y: margins.top,
            width: width - margins.right - margins.left,
            height: height - margins.top - margins.bottom,
            'pointer-events': 'all'
        });

axis_x = svg
        .append('g')
        .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'})        
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height-margins.bottom) + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.15, 12])
        .x(x)
        .on('zoom', function zoomHandler() {
            axis_x.call(xAxis);
            paths.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ', ' + margins.top + ') '
                + 'scale(' + d3.event.scale + ',1)');
        });

backRect.call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```

All project see with jsfiddle [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/yzeyd2sf/3/)

Instruction to see problem:

1. open link
2. wait 5-10 second
3. try to drag graph, after that the X-axis's position knock

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the *problem* part of this question.

Comment: @ksav sorry for my bad english :)
I will try to write more clearly

Comment: I think the graph always moves from its original position rather from its current position (having been dragged) ?

Comment: @Craicerjack But is it possible to somehow "synchronize" auto-refresh mode and user mode?

Comment: Im sure it is, I was just defining the problem, as i saw it, for @ksav

Comment: Ok I think I understand now ;)  Maybe the `AutoMode` transition never gets a chance to complete before you switch over to `UserMode`.